# Excel file is corrupted

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

After read and write an excel file using python modules xlrd and xlwt, my excel file is corrupted. I faced following prompt while opening using excel 2016. But, the file is opening perfectly in google sheets...

The error excel 2016 throwing is

"Can't open file beacuse the file format or file extension is not valid"

[image]

Comment: Whats your code (and maybe file if is not too big and have nothing important in it (you may want to makes a smaller example file with placeholder value)) ?

Comment: did you write the xlsx file using xlwt?

Comment: yes I am writing xlsx using xlwt

Comment: xlwt can only write to xls, probably the issue..try changing the extension or re-writing to proper filename

Comment: Thanks @DerekEden. It works fine with xls format

Comment: Seems like it is literally a typo then, since the file is written as a `.xls`, but is named `.xlsx`, which is the whole problem. Should probably close the question?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my above comment, the xlwt package (https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/) is only capable of writing to xls format.

Either change the extension of your file and try it, or change your code to save it as xls format.

I can't see your code but imagine it would look something like this:

```
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

when it should be

```
wb.save('example.xls')
```